# How can the oxidation of TEMPO be selective?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

According to the article "[**TEMPO oxidizes alcohols to aldehydes and ketones**](https://www.liskonchem.com/TEMPO-oxidizes-alcohols-to-aldehydes-and-ketones-id3275509.html)", the oxidation of TEMPO (2,2,6,6-tetramethylpiperidine-1-oxyl, 2564-83-2) can be highly selective. I assume it means you can easily choose to oxidize primary alcohol or secondary alcohol by controlling the conditions of reaction. But how to do that exactly? What conditions should be modified and how?

Comment: I have not done this reaction, but I think temperature and rate of oxidant addition will both be important factors in controlling selectivity

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I did a little research. Turns out PH value is the key. Secondary alcohols are more easily oxidized in a acidic environment than primary alcohols.

Comment: @SamLv *Suggest* Put your finding (e.g., one of the literature reference you found indicating the dependence of the rate of reaction / selectivity of the reaction on pH value; the structure of their molecule submitted to the oxidation, etc.) into an answer.  Other than a comment, answers (typically) stay on chemistry.se.